# Add delay between collection of tasks in executor service java

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

I've a collection of tasks being executed with executor service's invoke all method. The task locks the resource at beginning and unlocks at the end. But, sometimes the invokation of two tasks is so fast that the first resource is used by two tasks. Is there a way I can add a delay of a second before invoking next task

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class Sample {
    private boolean lock1 = false, lock2 = false;
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Sample obj = new Sample();
        try {
            obj.invoker();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean invoker() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

        boolean successFlag = true;
        ExecutorService exe = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

        List<Callable<Boolean>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        
        int counter[] = {1,2,3,4,5};

        for (int i: counter) {
            Callable<Boolean> task = () -> {
                return task(i);
            };
            tasks.add(task);
        }

        List<Future<Boolean>> ress = exe.invokeAll(tasks);
        for (Future<Boolean> res : ress) {
            successFlag &= res.get();
        }
        exe.shutdown();
        return successFlag;

    }

    public boolean task(int i) throws InterruptedException {
        if (!lock1) {
            updateLock("lock1", true);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(i + " is executed on resource 1");
            updateLock("lock1", false);
            return true;
        }

        if (!lock2) {
            updateLock("lock2", true);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println(i + " is executed on resource 2");
            updateLock("lock2", false);
            return true;
        }

        System.out.println(i + " couldn't be executed on either resource");
        return false;
    }
    
    private void updateLock(String lockName, boolean lock) {
        switch(lockName) {
            case "lock1":
                lock1 = lock;
                break;
                
            case "lock2":
                lock2 = lock;
                break;                
        }
    }
}
```

Its not every time but sometimes when I keep running the code, two tasks invoke at same moment and try to lock resource1.

Comment: how about posting some code that compiles?

Comment: @Eugene - done thanks

Comment: Have you considered using https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html
Instead of a boolean flag